# How to import module with the name of the module being a user input

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

As the title says I need the user to input the name of an account eg: Main or Spam and then import that specific module.

I tried using this but python expects to find a module called "Accounts" i wanted it to look for the module with the same name as the input

```
Account=input("Which account to use?: ")
    if Account in acc.accounts:
        import Account as info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use `import_module`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

module.py:

```py
def foo():
    print("bar")
```

In the script:

```py
from importlib import import_module
m = import_module("module") ## refers to module.py
m.foo() ## prints "bar"
```

In your code, you would want to change

```py
import Account as info
```

to

```py
info = import_module(Account)
```

You would want to make sure the module you are trying to import is also on your $PATH.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I LOVE YOU!!!!!! <3